# Steganography with Microsoft Word - DOCX

Tags: zip, docx, steganography

I write a application hide a of string within a .docx file.

A Docx file comprises of a collection of XML files that are contained inside a ZIP archive. So, My program treat that file like a zip file and hide secret string in it.

After research, I found a way to insert data to ZIP archive.

[image]

*A Secret String is injected after a file section right before the 1st central directory header. After that, a pointer in an end of central directory record is updated to compensate the shift of the central directory header.*

My output docx file work fine with typical file archivers (7-zip, WinRAR, File Roller, &c) or file managers (Windows Explorer).
But when I open my output docx file with Microsoft Word it said:

[image]

[Here is link for input and output file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QgrwTigdwVJSwmM3R7X2NP0smY4lqsZA?usp=sharing)

What step did I wrong or missing?

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using to inject the secret? Just as an FYI, your DOCX file works fine with other Word applications (like LibreOffice Writer). I know that Microsoft Word can be picky sometimes with DOCX content (unlike with DOC content, it will process any irregularities in it just fine...). Anyway, have you tried adding the secret with this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13808/Steganography-16-Hiding-additional-files-in-a-ZIP